# Why does $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(\ln(p))}{1+p^2}dp$ Converge?

Tags: integration, gamma-function, beta-function

I was messing around with the Dirichlet Beta Function and was able to get a formula:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(\ln(p))\ln(p)^{x-1}}{1+p^2}dp = \Gamma(x)(-1)^x(\beta'(x)-\beta(x)(i\pi +\psi(x)) $$
where $\beta(x)$ is the Dirichlet Beta Function and $\beta'(x)$ is its derivative. $\Gamma(x)$ is the Gamma Function and $\psi(x)$ is the Digamma Function and $i$ is the imaginary unit. Plugging in $1$ into the equation, you get the (what I thought to be cool) integral:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(\ln(p))}{1+p^2}dp = 2\ln(2)+3\ln(\pi)-4\ln(\Gamma(\frac{1}{4}))+i\frac{\pi^2}{4}$$

Looking at a graph and the function itself, it's not even defined from $0$ to $1$ on the real plane, so how is there even a way this integral has a real part? The only thing I can think of is an analytic continuation for the Gamma Function, but I don't really know anything about analytic continuation so it's just a hunch.

Comment: The formula takes $\ln (\ln p) = \ln \lvert \ln p\rvert + \pi i$ for $0 < p < 1$. Since the logarithm grows slowly, there's no convergence problem at either integral limit.

Comment: And you can also try the substitution $q={1\over p}$ to see what happens when the integration interval changes.

Comment: Ah I see thank you both!

Comment: Through the substitution $p=e^u$, Euler's Beta function and Feynman's trick it is not difficult to derive $$ \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\log\log p}{1+p^2}\,dp = \frac{\pi}{4}\log\left(\frac{4\pi^3}{\Gamma(1/4)^4}\right).$$

Comment: Thank you! I have fixed the question too.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I️ know this is extending this question a bit too thin, but I️ tried relating the integral to the beta function but I’m really struggling. Do you mind expanding your explanation?